# GitHub Actions run Espresso tests

Tags: continuous-integration, android-espresso, github-actions

I am currently trying to get my [Instrumentation tests](https://github.com/qbalsdon/currency_list_app/blob/feature/espresso_ci/.github/workflows/android-feature.yml) to run using GitHub Actions. I have the unit tests running fine but I cannot seem to get the Espresso tests to run. I am currently trying:

```
    - name: Run Instrumentation Tests (reactivecircus)
    uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2.6.1
    with:
      api-level: 23
      target: default
      arch: x86
      profile: Nexus 6
      script: ./gradlew connectedCheck --stacktrace
```

And I get the result:

```
com.balsdon.ratesapp.behaviour.RateListActivityEntryBehaviourInstrumentedTest > recyclerViewClickOnItemChangesMain[test(AVD) - 6.0] FAILED 
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700d3
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
Tests on test(AVD) - 6.0 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException'

> Task :app:connectedOfflinemockDebugAndroidTest FAILED
> Task :app:processOnlineecbDebugAndroidTestResources
> Task :app:processProductionDebugAndroidTestResources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedOfflinemockDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/currency_list_app/currency_list_app/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/OFFLINEMOCK/index.html
```

and when I use:

```
    - uses: malinskiy/action-android/emulator-run-cmd@release/0.0.5
    with:
      cmd: ./gradlew integrationTest
      api: 23
      tag: default
      abi: x86
```

I get

```
/Users/runner/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop sys.boot_completed
error: device 'emulator-5554' not found
The process '/Users/runner/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' failed with exit code 1
```

If you want to see all my attempts, you can see all the commits [on my pull request](https://github.com/qbalsdon/currency_list_app/pull/24)

Comment: I didn't have any trouble creating a github action using `reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2` with `./gradlew connectedCheck` script on a project having Espresso UI testing even with [your emulator settings `api-level: 23 ...`](https://github.com/clytras/android-espresso-basic/actions/runs/69832873/workflow). You can check it out here [Android Espresso Test CI / test](https://github.com/clytras/android-espresso-basic/runs/557844461?check_suite_focus=true). Are the tests pass when running locally?

Comment: Yep the tests pass locally - I'll take a look at yours

Comment: Surely if my tests where failing the lib should report that though? Just an after thought while this is going. So glad there is a project using this stuff I can look at though - thank you

Comment: Yeah so reactivecircus starts the emulator but it can't find the resources for some reason - I keep getting the error described in the question. I just ran the tests locally and they all pass when I run `./gradlew connectedCheck --stacktrace` from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, the issue is about the resources for some reason are not attached. My example is a very simple one, just a basic Espresso gradle project from Google and a very simple Github action. I'll look at your project source code for culprits regarding this issue.

Comment: I found the issue. Locally, you most likely have an emulator with a newer than `API 23` android version. On github actions you're running the emulator using `API 23` and inside your project there is a `app/src/main/res/drawable-v24` inside resources, thus it wont be available for emulators with `< 24 API` version. I've tried to run the test after renaming the directory to `drawable-v23`; it can find the resources but there seems to be more issues running espresso on older API versions. If it's fine to change the emulator API version to a compatible espresso version, I can provide an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Christos Lytras - that's the fix. Wow if you could please put that in an answer and I'll award you the bounty

Comment: I have put an answer in place just in the meantime

Comment: Thank you I have just put an answer. Are you going to bump version up to the Github actions or you'll refactor the tests to be compatible with `API 23`?

Comment: Since I want to espresso tests to run on my min sdk, I went with 23. I tried bumping it to v24, but there were other issues and I needed to fix tests anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your emulator version that you run locally, it's most likely newer than `API 23` android version. On [github actions script](https://github.com/qbalsdon/currency_list_app/pull/24/commits/fecadad42ace37c2f5bea3b52ec01db11f7e2b0f#diff-0b095e3589a82b58c4b444ed2229b7d0R57) you're running the emulator using `API 23`:

```
    uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
    with:
      api-level: 23
      target: default
      arch: x86
      profile: Nexus 6
      script: ./gradlew connectedCheck --stacktrace
```

and inside your project there is a `app/src/main/res/drawable-v24` inside resources, thus it wont be available for emulators with `< 24 API` version. You either have to change that directory to be `drawable-v23` or you move the resources to an other `drawable` that older versions can access.

Even if you change the drawable directory to `drawable-v23`, Espresso may have issues. You'll either have to resolve for that version or you'll have to use a newer API version for your GitHub action emulator, maybe the same as you have on your development environment.